# How to merge subtree changes upstream

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm following the subtree walk-through from [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html).

I'm at the point where I want to merge local changes I've made in my subtree upstream to the original repository, but the walk-through doesn't specify what command should be run.

To merge into my local branch, I can use:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit rack_branch
```

What is the command to merge into `rack_branch` from `master` (assuming the subtree directory is `Rack/`)?

From the documentation:

> All the changes from your Rack project are merged in and ready to be committed locally. You can also do the opposite — make changes in the rack subdirectory of your master branch and then merge them into your rack_branch branch later to submit them to the maintainers or push them upstream.

But it doesn't give you any guidance on the actual command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate answering my own question, but in case someone stumbles here this might help out.

The first article I referenced (part of the git-scm book), is out of date.  The best method to do this is to use the git subtree command.

[This article](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) explains it it detail.  The process is much simpler than using git merge subtree.

Comment: That's funny. I was referencing the article you linked in your answer, and had to search google because it was missing some information that prevented `git merge -s ours --no-commit tpope-vim-surround/master` from working. My google search brought me here, and your original question links to a webpage that solved my issue.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger care to include the gist of the workflow? See also this [meta post on linking as answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)